# Adding Values From List To specific Column In Layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to develop a plugin in QGIS 3.0, and I'm stuck.

A major component of my plugin is the ability to append a list of composite values as a new column to the vector layer of focus.

How do I add the values from a list to a specific column in a layer, with PYQGIS?

I've tried the following, but the column came back as empty.

```
    # List In Focus
    composite_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    # Reference The Vector Layer In Focus
    lyrOutput = QgsVectorLayer(file_path, name + "_", "ogr")
    provider = lyrOutput.dataProvider()

    # Add A new Column To The Vector File
    provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Composite", QVariant.Double)])
    lyrOutput.updateFields()

    # Add Data To Composite Field
    comp_index = lyrOutput.fieldNameIndex('Composite')
    idx = comp_index
    lyrOutput.startEditing()

    for comp in lyrOutput.getFeature():
        lyrOutput.changeAttributeValue(comp.id(), idx, composite_list[0])
    lyrOutput.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited your code slightly from when you want to add data to the composite field:

- Used the `edit` method which combines `startEditing()` and `commitChanges()` into a single loop.
- Added the `i` parameter to iterate through the list with each feature.
- Added a `try` method just in case there is a situation where the number of values in your list does not match the number of features, otherwise there will be an `indexError`. If this occurs, the feature will take the last value in the list.

---

Here is the code:

```
# List In Focus
composite_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# Reference The Vector Layer In Focus
lyrOutput = QgsVectorLayer(file_path, name + "_", "ogr")
provider = lyrOutput.dataProvider()

# Add A new Column To The Vector File
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("Composite", QVariant.Double)])
lyrOutput.updateFields()

# Add Data To Composite Field
with edit(lyrOutput):
    for feature in lyrOutput.getFeatures():
        try:
            feature.setAttribute('Composite', composite_list[i])
            i += 1
            lyrOutput.updateFeature(feature)
        except IndexError:
            feature.setAttribute('Composite', composite_list[-1])
            lyrOutput.updateFeature(feature)
```