# Writing list as attribute field in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, list, vector-field

This answer got me close https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/286780/204059, but I only get the last value of my list for all object fields.

Example: My list = [REL_1, REL_2, REL_3]. My layer has three objects. All objects get value REL_3.

How can I fix this?

```py
#count features
feat_count = layer.featureCount()

#write name_list
name_list = []
for i in range(feat_count):
    rel_name = ('REL_{}'.format(i)) 
    name_list.append(rel_name)

# add data to 'name' field
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        try:
            feature.setAttribute('name', name_list[i])
            i += 1
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
        except IndexError:
            feature.setAttribute('name', name_list[-1])
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you have a reason for creating the list in a loop like you do, but as your example is written it would appear you can skip that step and shorten your code to:

```py
with edit(layer):
    # use enumerate to iterate the features
    for i,feature in enumerate(list(layer.getFeatures())):
        feature.setAttribute('name', f'REL_{i+1}')
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You need to reset the `i` variable. Because after the first `for`, Python remembers the last value of `i`. After the first `for` `i` value is 2 and `name_list[2]` is `REL_3`.

Add `i = 0` before `for feature in layer.getFeatures():`